# Migration of API from API Manager Dev environment to Test environment using Migration tool

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I'm trying to push an API from API Manager Dev environment to Test environment using Migration tool, for the change in the backend URL's and Auth credentials do we need to go for every API and make changes or do we have any configurations to make changes? Please suggest !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each endpoint usually has its own credentials, there is no way you can set a single credential for all endpoints. So you have to make the change for each API.